# Problem uploading NSString to server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I am struggling to get one particular string to upload, using php and mysql I have a number of strings from textfields that will successfully go, this particular string is the text from a label in another viewcontroller. I can see the text with NSLog but for some reason it will not go, I'm confident the server side is working properly as I can pass other strings to that particular row in mySQL.
To get the text from the other view I am using

```
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender;
    {

    GetLocation * getlocation =[[GetLocation alloc] initWithNibName:Nil bundle:nil];    
    getlocation.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    getlocation.rwanswer=self.rwanswer.text;
    [self presentModalViewController:getlocation animated:YES];

    [getlocation release];
}
```

in the first viewcontroller then in the view that is uploading to the server I synthesize the string.

```
NSString *rwanswer;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *rwanswer;
```

I can see the text with NSLog but for some reason I cannot get it to upload.

```
-(IBAction)UploadData :(id)sender {


    NSString *appname = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];


    NSString *result =rwanswer;
    NSLog(@"result=%@", result);

    NSString *comment =comments.text;
    NSString *name = username.text;
    NSLog(@"name=%@", name);

    NSString *Website =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.ivectorn.com/Set/Submit.php?name=%@&comments=%@&appname=%@&results=%@", name, comment, appname,  result];
    [BackroundLoader loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Website]]];
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Can you do NSLog(@"Website string%@",Website); after NSString* Website line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this problem. I think the problem is by your Website-String. Try to Log int and you will see, that there are characters inside you cannot put in a URL. The following method will help you if this is your problem:

```
- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

Instead of

```
NSString *appname = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];


NSString *result =rwanswer;
NSLog(@"result=%@", result);

NSString *comment =comments.text;
NSString *name = username.text;
```

To the following:

```
NSString *appname = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  //Or your String Encoding


NSString *result = [rwanswer stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  //Or your String Encoding;
NSLog(@"result=%@", result);

NSString *comment =[comments.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  //Or your String Encoding;
NSString *name = [username.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  //Or your String Encoding;
```

I hope this will help you. I struggled with the same problem some time ago.

Sandro Meier

Comment: You're welcome. I know it because I tried about one day until I came across this method. ;-)